# Database Design: User turn fields on or off

Tags: database-design, many-to-many

I'm looking for a pattern that allows a user to turn on or off a field. If I have a `CAR` table, I would have a many-to-many link table called `CAR_OPTION` that links options (CD player, leather seats, etc.) to a car.

I would like users to be able to select which of these potential options they would like for a car and then store that data, such that the user can see which of the potential options they have turned on/off. I've gone through a bunch of this in my head and all of my solutions feel like they are reinventing the wheel. The only half-decent solution I have involves creating another many-to-many table that also has an id field to bind back to that user `ORDER`, something like `CAR_OPTION_ORDER` that I would then overlay for the delta on `CAR_OPTION` in the UI code

Is that the best option or are there some other common practices or patterns for this scenario? My solution just feels like a lot of the same/similar data stored multiple times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the best option in my opinion. It's called an associative entity. I read once long ago to add an identity primary key / clustered index rather than using the two foreign keys as a primary key. That's been my SOP and joins perform very well.

On the reporting / historical analysis side I might use a different design if the load was heavy.

Comment: Well alright then. Thank you for the term, finding that is usually an uphill battle for me.

Comment: I agree this is the best design -- a three-way intersection table between Users, Cars and Options. However, I disagree about creating a separate identity key. It simply has no purpose. You query the database knowing the User and/or the Car and/or the Option of interest. That is: For user U and Car C, is Option O enabled? For User U and Car C, which options are enabled? Or analysis: Which is the most popular Option selected for Car C?
At no time will you ever query the database using the value of the key. It is, at best, superfluous.